# React: what are use cases when we need React.Children api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just trying to find any use case for `React.Children` api. Reading docs is confusing. (React v. 15.2.0)

> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children

Here they say, that `this.props.children` is *'opaque data structure'*. But when debugging in chrome dev tools, it looks like `children` is an array.
So functions like `React.Children.map` or `React.Children.toArray` don't make so much sense, as Array.prototype.map can be used instead of the first one, and the last produces the same result as original `children` property.

For me it looks like docs are outdated (I didn't use react 0.14.*, so I don't know what situation was there), or I am missing something. Will be glad if somebody can explain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.Children` is, as the documentation explains, a set of utilities for a components children. In this case (jsx):

```
<div>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
</div>
```

Your `div`'s `children` would be an array of the two `span`s. Consider a self-closing component:

```
<div>
   <SomeCustomElement/>
</div>
```

In this case, `div` has a single child, but `this.props.children` in `SomeCustomElement` would be `null`. So trying to call `this.props.children.map` would in some cases throw an error, since the `children` prop does not follow a strict typing convention.

`React.Children` does two things. It "fixes" (some would say circumvents) the before-mentioned by providing some common tools that allows you to not care about whether `this.props.children` is `null`, an array, a keyed fragment or whatever so you don't fill up your component with `if`, `switch` and such just to iterate over its children. Also, it ensures forward compatibility. It's arguable that a better way would just to stick to a strict type, providing an empty array instead of `null`, an array with a single element if the only child is a keyed fragment and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing in JavaScript is really opaque.  The deal here is that the React team considers the current implementation of `children` to be exactly that: implementation details.

They tell you to treat the data as opaque and only access it through their `React.Children` API so that they have the freedom to change the underlying data structure in the future without worrying about breaking existing apps.

If you do not use `React.Children` API and instead use the underlying `Array` prototype methods, then you are using unsupported implementation details and you risk having your code stop working with some new version of React.

Comment: Both answers are great, but I think, Dencker's answer better explains reasons behind this api. Thanks!